# Nested List in Android with ArrayAdapter and different ObjectTypes

Tags: android, android-listview

I have the following problem. I have 3 types of Objects:

Devices,
Directories,
Songs

Right now I am only displaying my Devices with 
`ArrayAdapter<DeviceDisplay>`

How can I display all 3 types in the same list?

Also Id like to only show Directories of a given Device when I click on it in the list, and only the songs of a Directory when clicked on.

Also I am using everything inside a Fragment.

Is this somehow achievable?

Code in my fragment:

```
public class MusicListFragment extends ListFragment {

    ArrayAdapter<DeviceDisplay> mediaServerAdapter;
    ArrayList<Device> mediaServers = new ArrayList<Device>();
    ArrayList<Container> containers = new ArrayList<Container>();
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_list, container, false);

        getMediaServers();

        mediaServerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<DeviceDisplay>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        setListAdapter(mediaServerAdapter);
        addDevicesToAdapter();


        return rootView;
    }



    public void getMediaServers(){
        Activity a = getActivity();
        ArrayList<Device> devices = ((MainActivity) a).getDevices();
        for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
            Device device = devices.get(i);
            if( device.getType().getType().equals( "MediaServer" ) ){
                if (!mediaServers.contains(device)) {
                    mediaServers.add(device);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void addDevicesToAdapter(){
        for (int i = 0; i < mediaServers.size() ; i++) {
            mediaServerAdapter.add(new DeviceDisplay(mediaServers.get(i)));
            listContent(mediaServers.get(i));
        }
    }

    public void listContent(Device device){

        System.out.println(device.getDisplayString());
        Service service = device.findService(new UDAServiceId("ContentDirectory"));


        ActionCallback browse = new Browse(service, "0", BrowseFlag.DIRECT_CHILDREN) {

            @Override
            public void received(ActionInvocation actionInvocation, DIDLContent didl) {

                //Containers and songs come here.

            }

            @Override
            public void updateStatus(Status status) {

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(ActionInvocation invocation,
                                UpnpResponse operation,
                                String defaultMsg) {

            }
        };



        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).upnpService.getControlPoint().execute(browse);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best soultion, but you can make base class for your `DeviceDisplay`, `Directories` and so on, whick looks like this :

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    public abstract int getViewType();

}
```

Then extend your classes from it, override the `getViewType()`

And give List as adapter items

Then override this methods in your adapter:

```
@Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return items.get(position).getViewType()
    }
```

And in your `getView` you can go just like this:

```
switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
//Here you know which type this item has and you can draw it whatever you want
}
```